# How to identify which button is clicked in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton, sender

I am a new iPad developer.

I have created UIButton programmatically, in which I want to identify user has clicked on which button and according to that I want to do some action.

How should I identify this?

Here is my code snippet:

```
for(int i=0;i<[_array count];i++)
    {

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.tag=count;
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(aMethod:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(xpos, 270.0, 200.0, 150.0);

        [self.view addSubview:button];            
    }
```

**This is what I'm doing now:** I thought I will assign count to each button and I will pass this count to button click method. Is this a good idea? Is there any other way possible?

On button click I'm calling `aMethod`:

```
-(void)aMethod:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"btn clicked");

}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your logic and idea. you could access `tag` in your button to differentiate between each other. and Yes, I could say, it's good idea. I did this way on my projects as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
-(void)aMethod:(UIButton*)sender{
    NSLog(@"btn clicked %d", sender.tag);

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use the button's tag to identify which button has been pressed.

Comment: This is the way I would do it. I believe using the tag property is the standard way of identifying the button.